Does exterior power commute with dual for modules over a commutative ring?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Let $M^\vee:=\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,R)$ denote the dual module. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
There is a natural paring
$$\wedge^nM\;\otimes_R\;\wedge^n(M^\vee)\to R$$
given by
$$(f_1\wedge\cdots\wedge f_n)\otimes(g^1\wedge\cdots\wedge g^n)\mapsto\det\big(g^i(f_j)\big). $$
This leads to
$$\wedge^n(M^\vee)\to \big(\wedge^n M\big)^\vee. $$
Is the above map always an isomorphism? I know it is for finite free modules when I can check on basis. I am not sure general modules.

I believe it already fails when $M$ is free of infinite rank. Try to check this situation.

I thought Quadratic Mappings and Clifford Algebras by Helmstetter and Micali would have a definitive answer, but all I see is that, on the middle of page 187, "it is obviously an isomorphism when $M$ is a free module of finite rank; consequently it is still an isomorphism when $M$ is a finitely generated projective module." Note that in this book $R$ need not be commutative.

One simple way to construct a counterexample is to build a finitely generated $R$- module $M$ (say over a local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$) for which (in your notation) $M^{\vee}$ requires a different number of minimal generators than $M$. This will cause, for appropriate choices of $n$, for one of $\bigwedge^n_R(M)$ or $\bigwedge^n_R(M^{\vee})$ to be $0$ while the other is not.
For a simple such example, let $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ and take $M=k \cong R/(x,y)$. One can show that $k^{\vee} \cong k^{\oplus 2}$ with a generating set for $k^{\vee}$ given by $\{f,g\}$ where $f$ is given by $1 \mapsto x$ and $g$ by $1 \mapsto y$.
Then $\bigwedge^2_R(M)=0$, since $M$ is cyclic, so that in particular $\bigwedge^2_R(M)^{\vee}=0$, while $\bigwedge^2_R(M^{\vee}) \cong \bigwedge^2_R(k^{\oplus 2}) \cong k$.
